# How to dismiss number keyboard after tapping outside of the textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How would you dismiss the keyboard from the UITextField when tapping outside of the keyboard? I have tried `resignFirstResponder()` and it only exits after typing one number. I have also tried `textField.inputView = UIView.frame(frame: CGRectZero)`. I have seen many Objective-C verisons of what I'm asking but I need the Swift equivalent because I have no programming experience in Objective-C.

Comment: textField.resignFirstResponder() should work correctly. Here is a sample example uploaded https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0vm89gd6uegpn0/textfield.zip?dl=0

Comment: Also do check your/mine code on the actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use this method to dismiss the keyboard when pressing 'Return'

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        return false;
}
```

Make sure to set your delegate

Answer (score 18):

The best way to add a tap gesture recognizer to the view and calling either resignFirstResponder() or self.view.endEditing(true). I prefer endEditing() since resignFirstResponder has to be done for each text field separately unlike endEditing which is done for the view itself.

In viewDidLoad, write the below code:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "didTapView")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Now write the didTapView method to dismiss the keyboard:

```
func didTapView(){
  self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Now when you tap outside the keyboard on the main view of the controller, it will call the didTapView method and dismiss the keyboard.

**Swift 3.x**

The code in viewDidLoad should be:

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTapView))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

where ViewController should be the name of your view controller.

Thanks

Comment: where do i put the didTapView function

Comment: Just add the func inside the same view controller class that you have.

Comment: Swift 3 required me to add in a selector, as follows 
`tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.didTapView))`

Comment: Added Swift 3 Syntax as well. Thanks @ChristyHerron

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3 tested and working**

```
 // dismiss keyboard on touch outside textfield
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for txt in self.view.subviews {
            if txt.isKind(of: UITextField.self) && txt.isFirstResponder {
                txt.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

**Enjoy**

**Swift 2.3 tested and working**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for txt in self.view.subviews {
            if txt.isKindOfClass(UITextField.self) && txt.isFirstResponder() {
                txt.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
```

**Enjoy**

Comment: It's a lot simpler if you replace the whole `for` loop with a simple call to `self.view.endEditing(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    
    if textField.isFirstResponder {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to define an extra method, there is a slightly simpler way that will also work

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "endEditing:")
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Comment: Using this I get the error, `use of string literal for Objective-C seletors is deprecated; use '#selector' instead`. I'll post if I find the solution.

Comment: endEditing: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: This is a bad idea because the `endEditing:` method has one parameter of type `Bool`. But added as the action of gesture recognizer means the selected will be called with a value of `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of a `Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code on a site and it works great for me!

```
//FUNCTION TO DISMISS THE KEYBOARD
 func initializeHideKeyboard(){
 //Declare a Tap Gesture Recognizer which will trigger our dismissMyKeyboard() function
 let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
 target: self,
 action: #selector(dismissMyKeyboard))
 //Add this tap gesture recognizer to the parent view
 view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }

 @objc func dismissMyKeyboard(){
 //endEditing causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
 //In short- Dismiss the active keyboard.
 view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

Then just call this function in a button action or similar:

```
dismissMyKeyboard()
```