# Dismiss the Number Pad with a custom table view cell with TextField

Tags: ios

i have a tableview with a custom cell and a textfield on it. Like image below.

[image: Custom Cell]

Class of the Custom Cell:

```
import UIKit

protocol TextFieldTableDelegate{
    func retornaTexto(sender: TextFieldTableViewCell, texto: String)
}

class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var delegate: TextFieldTableDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.textField.delegate = self
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.delegate!.retornaTexto(self, texto: textField.text!)
        return true
    }

}
```

This delegate method is never called

```
    func retornaTexto(sender: TextFieldTableViewCell, texto: String) {
        print(texto)
        codigoAreaSelecionada = texto
    }
```

The problem is, after i touch the textfield it opens a Number Pad, but when i touch outside it (on the background) it doesn't dismiss.

i've tried this [Swift - How to dismiss number keyboard after tapping outside of the textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878732/swift-how-to-dismiss-number-keyboard-after-tapping-outside-of-the-textfield) but it broke all other touches things in the view.

EDIT: i make the Number Pad keyboard hide and show adding this to my viewController, but it not trigger the delegate method.

```
var tapRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer?
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    view.removeGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer!)
}
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTapView")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer!)
}

func didTapView(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

EDIT:

i've changed the method:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   self.delegate!.retornaTexto(self, texto: textField.text!)
   return true
}
```

with:
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

```
    if let texto = textField.text{
        self.delegate!.retornaTexto(self, texto: texto)
    }
}
```

but it stops without a console warning on the call of retornaTexto.

Answer (score 1):

textFieldShouldReturn gets called when a TextField that has a full keyboard has the Return key tapped on it.  The numeric keypad doesn't have a return key, so this isn't going to work for your case.

Probably the correct approach is to add a gesture recognizer to a view outside of the textbox (maybe the viewcontroller's view?) to dismiss the keyboard (like the question you referenced); but do this on the keyboard show; and remove it on the keyboard hide.  There are UINotification events you can hook into for these events: See [How to detect when keyboard is shown and hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374436/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-shown-and-hidden)

You can also use these events to change the table insets for the table so the number entry cell is visable above  the keyboard on smaller phones as well!

Comment: it works, but the func retornaTexto(sender: TextFieldTableViewCell, texto: String) is never executed, so i'm not able to take the value of the field on my delegate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try another method, modify the `keyboardDismissMode` property of `UITableView`.

Here is the cleanest way to achieve this in iOS 7.0.

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Or to dismiss when touch

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

---

#### UPDATE

I think that you can implement this delegate method about the end of editing.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField  
{
    // receive the end of editing of UITextField.
}
```

Or, obtain the editing event by the following way.

```
// Add a "textFieldDidChange" notification method to the text field control.
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: this way dismiss the keyboard, but how can i trigger the retornaTexto(sender: TextFieldTableViewCell, texto: String)  method with this?

Comment: i've changed the func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool { with -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField, but it stops woking on the delegate call line.

Comment: What it means about `stop working` ? If it crashes, you can add break points about `All Exceptions` to catch the error. [Refer this page](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions).